# Using li-ion battery in place of a lead acid one in a desk lamp

Tags: lithium-ion, lead-acid

I have a rechargeable desk led lamp with USB power input. Although it's supposed to hold charge, it only works when plugged. I opened it and found that the problem is about included lead acid rechargeable battery.

I cut out the broken battery and connected a li-ion 3.7v in its place that I got from an old broken cellphone.

Lamp lights up just fine now but I'm afraid to connect the lamp to a power source since li ion and lead acid are different type of batteries. Am I creating a potential fire hazard or is it fine?

[image: picture of the old battery]

Comment: It's a severe fire hazard and will almost certainly end badly. A lithium ion battery must ONLY be charged using a circuit that is specifically designed to charge it safely.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to replace the original battery, lead acid would be exceedingly unusual in a desk lamp.  Are you 100% sure?

Comment: Actually there isn't any label on the battery but it looks like those in solar powered toys for kids.

Comment: How about posting a picture of the battery?

Comment: What if I use a Li ion charger circuit between old terminals and the battery? Circuit says it's for single cell li-ion but I don't know if the phone battery is single cell.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I added the picture of the battery that came out the lamp.

Comment: Lead-acid batteries are commonly used in emergency lights - but those are normally charged from AC.  I wouldn't expect a lead-acid battery in a desk lamp intended to be charged by USB.  Perhaps you have NiCD or NiMH?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not fine.  Lithium batteries have different charge profiles, and must be managed more closely than the relatively forgiving lead-acid batteries.  Doing this could result in dead battery, or even fire.  And, you don't even seem to know the nominal voltage of the lead-acid battery.

All around **BAD IDEA**